# jQuery File Upload: Detect if same file selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, uploadify, jquery-file-upload

I use jQuery File Upload plugin for my website.

After user presses a "Browse..." button I call uploadadd callback.
However, it fires EVERYTIME user adds the file. Even if he adds the SAME FILE.

What I need is to either fire uploadadd callback only once per each unique file or to get unique identifier of the file so I can store it in an array of files. In this case I can detect if file has been already selected.

I tried to use data-array of callback's function:

```
function (e, data) { }
```

but it contains only filesize/filename/filetype info so I can't create an unique hash from it since two or more files can have same info.

Here is my code:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: "/upload/",
    dataType: 'json',
    autoUpload: false,
    add: function (e, data) {
        console.log(data.files[0]);
        qcount += 1;
        $('#select-button').text(qcount + ' files');

        data.submit();
    });
});
```

In Uploadify plugin I can use onAddQueueItem callback but jQuery-File-Upload doesn't seem to have same functionality.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: "/upload/",
    dataType: 'json',
    autoUpload: false,
    add: function (e, data) {
        data.files = $.map(data.files, function(file,i){
            if ($.inArray(file.name,currentfiles) >= 0) { 
                alert("file exists");
                return null; 
            }
            return file;
        });

        console.log(data.files[0]);
        qcount += 1;
        $('#select-button').text(qcount + ' files');

        data.submit();
    });
});
```

You don't have to use `file.name`. You could use `file.name` + `file.size` as a hash.

Comment: I can't use file.name + file.size as a hash since it's not safe. What if there are two files named "1.jpg" and 1024 bytes in size?

Comment: Well, I tried your source code but it fails when I upload two different images but with same filename & filesize.

Comment: Which is more important to you - two files having the same name and filesize? You can always code on the backend to catch one or the other. I think it would make more sense to catch same filesize and filename on the front end, but if you want to allow people to do that, then, okay.

Comment: I need to catch it on front end to show files count. Your code fails to do it. It doesn't count different files which have same name & size. What I need is to count each file, excluding itself only.